# How to view the lists and folders that Limited Access Groups can see

Tags: permissions

I can view what lists have unique permissions and I can view what groups are marked as limited access.  However, if you give a group permissions for a folder, it will list that group as having limited access on the site and in that folder.  It can be confusing and difficult to know what a limited access group has access to and what it doesn't have access to...without testing.

I want to be able to view a group that has limited access and to know exactly what that group has access to.  For example:

My Test Group - Limited access
The group has access to the following folders/lists...

Where or how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within site permissions, use the "Check Permissions" button. Enter the name of the group in question and click "Check Now".

Comment: Actually, all I get when I do that is "limited access" which is the problem I am trying to resolve.  I want it to tell me what folders does this limited access group have access to, if it is indeed just a folder.

Comment: You could use powershell to get a group's permissions within a site. For example: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c502cd5-04a0-4b9e-a35a-dd7e9cd6d431/get-permission-levels-of-a-sharepoint-group-using-powershell-script-?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Sounds good, unfortuantely this is for a company site and I have no access to SharePoint designer or the ability to use powershell as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Go to group and unser settings click view group permissions which will display all the included resources and respective permissions on them